# How to download objects from AWS S3 outside application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, download, amazon-s3

I am downloading AWS-S3 objects using:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3client);
        GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, entity.getName());
            String s="";
            download = transferManager.download(bucket, entity.getName(), f);
```

I want to continue downloading objects after I exit my application.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with S3. You just need to do long running process like download in `Service`. Or if the objects have ACL set to public you can use `DownloadManager` and use the objects' url instead of instantiating AWS client or `TransferManager` . [This](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager) is AWS example that I use to do download.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  If you look at http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxGY67VAIX09HV/Pause-and-Resume-Amazon-S3-Transfers-Using-the-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-Android it shows how to pause current Upload/Downloads and serialize them to disk.  You could do this whenever you believe your application is exiting.

Thanks,
Weston